# How to call oncreate of the activity from its fragment class?

Tags: android

I need to call `onCreate` of the calling `activity` from its `fragment` without using `intent` ?

I have used something like this :

```
Intent mainIntent = new Intent( get Activity() , MainActivity.class);
( (MainActivity)getActivity() ).startActivity( mainIntent );
```

is there any other way to call the `onCreate` of the `activity` from its `fragment`?

Comment: May be done using coustem receiver but why it needed this

Comment: onCreate is called automatically by the system when Activity is starting. Why would you need to call it from Fragment? Try to be more specific about what you trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply call

```
getActivity().onCreate()
```

Comment: its not working for me. i'm getting illegal state expection. ((MainActivity)getActivity()).onCreate(mSavedFragmentState);